# dojo manipulate with innerHTML to set to empty string, does not work, why?

Tags: javascript, dojo

So I do a dojo.require for node-manipulate and it works fine to do things like, dojo.query(".theclass").innerHTML("new content"); so that "new content" gets written to all the theclass, but, when I attempt dojo.query(".theclass").innerHTML(""); it fails silently and doesnt replace the content that was there before with the empty string. Why is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

dojo docs suggests the next solution

```
dojo.query(".theclass").forEach(dojo.empty);
```

BTW I don't understand, how `dojo.query(...).innerHTML(...)` works for you at all.

Comment: It works because dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-manipulate"); gives it. I know I could use empty, or do it by hand instead of dojo. But thats not the point, innerHTML says it will set stuff, but it doesnt if the stuff is an empty string, A " " works fine though. Why is that?

Comment: Didn't use dojo too much, but cuurent version on dojo site provides array, which doesn't have innerHTML method.

Comment: If you require the dojo.NodeList-manipulate then you get the innerHTML to use on all the NodeLists which dojo.query gives.